# iOS Release build issue

Tags: ios, swift, opencv, release, testflight

I'm working on an iOS app which uses OpenCV to detect objects and am facing a weird issue with the release builds. The app detects correctly identifies the object when the app is run from Xcode but when the build is installed from TestFlight, the object detection doesn't work properly. Below are the two images from the different builds:

App Installed from Xcode: https://ibb.co/8BLb1mh 
App Installed from TestFlight: https://ibb.co/H4wz1jg

I'm testing the app on iOS 13.6 and the app is built using Xcode 11.6. Unless someone faced an exactly similar issue, I'm specifically looking into advise regarding what should be debugged. Any idea what could be wrong or what can I do to investigate this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be Build Setting specific to `Release` which caused the issue for me.

For Release I had the `Optimization Level` set to `Optimize for Speed`. Changing this to `No Optimization` fixed the issue for me.